# Find the point where locus crosses the damping ratio line?

Tags: control-engineering

Given a transfer function, find the point where locus crosses the damping ratio of 0.5?

$$G(s)= \dfrac{K(s-2)(s-4)}{s^2+6s+25}$$

The textbook only shows this solved by Matlab or program, I would like to know how to do it by hand calculations?

Answer (score 0):

Solve the closed-loop equation:
$$T(s) = \frac{G(s)}{1+G(s)} = \frac{K(s^2-6s+8)}{s^2+6s+25+K(s^2-6s+8)}$$

structure the denominator to the following:
$$s^2 + as+b$$
and relate to the denominator of the standard second order mass model:
$$H(s) = \frac{Q\omega^2}{s^2+2\zeta\omega s+ \omega^2}$$
where $Q$ is any arbitrary gain. Relate $K$ to $\zeta$ such that $\zeta = 0.5$.
$$T(s) = \frac{K(s^2-6s+8)}{s^2(1+K)+s(6-6K)+25+8K}$$
$$T(s) = \frac{K(s^2-6s+8)/(1+K)}{s^2+s(6-6K)/(1+K) + (25+8K)/(1+K)}$$
$$2\zeta = \frac{6-6K}{1+K}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{1+K}}{\sqrt{25+8K}}$$
$$2\zeta = \frac{(6-6K)\sqrt{1+K}}{\sqrt{1+K}^2\sqrt{25+8K}} = \frac{(6-6K)}{\sqrt{(1+K)(25+8K)}} = 1$$
$$\rightarrow 8K^2+33K+25 = (6-6K)^2$$
Solve this and mind the sign. due to the squared structure, on $K$ value will yield a damping value of $-0.5$. so plug the result back into the equation to verify the correct one.